# Windows Presentation Foundation Host Crash in Chrome

Tags: wpf, google-chrome

we have an application with XBAP and one of our users is getting an error only on Chrome.
it cannot load the Windows Presentation Foundation Host Plugin, although it shows on the plugins list. what can we check? its win XP .

Comment: Make sure Windows Presentation Foundation isn't disabled in `chrome://plugins`. Also, make sure plugins aren't disabled in `chrome://settings/content`.

Comment: both are checked and enabled.

Comment: I haven't used WPF, so I don't really know... :(